# Why is this assembly "marked with the AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute", and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: .net, security

I'm playing around with a [Boo](https://github.com/bamboo/boo/) interpreter and trying to embed it into a simple program.  Everything works fine, right up until I try to get it to evaluate an expression.  Then I get this:

```
>> System.MethodAccessException: Attempt by security transparent method 
'Boo.Lang.Interpreter.AbstractInterpreter.ExecuteEntryPoint(
System.Reflection.Assembly)' to access security critical method
'System.AppDomain.add_AssemblyResolve(System.ResolveEventHandler)' failed.

Assembly 'Boo.Lang.Interpreter, Version=2.0.9.4, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=32c39770e9a21a67' is marked with the
AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute, and uses the level 2 security transparency
model. Level 2 transparency causes all methods in AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers
assemblies to become security transparent by default, which may be the cause of this
exception.
   at Boo.Lang.Interpreter.AbstractInterpreter.ExecuteEntryPoint(Assembly asm)
   at Boo.Lang.Interpreter.AbstractInterpreter.EvalCompileUnit(CompileUnit cu)
   at Boo.Lang.Interpreter.AbstractInterpreter.EvalCompilerInput(ICompilerInput input)
   at Boo.Lang.Interpreter.AbstractInterpreter.Eval(String code)
   ...
```

I've run a full search over both the Boo source code and my own project, and `AllowPartiallyTrustedCallersAttribute` is not referenced anywhere at all, so I have no idea why the interpreter is "marked with" it.

From searching around online, just about everything I find about this problem is related to ASP.NET, which I am not using.  The solutions say to stick something or other in `web.config`, which I don't have because I am not using ASP.NET, or to configure some permissions somewhere in IIS, **which I don't have because I am not bloody using ASP.NET!**

So, does anyone have any idea what is really going on here and how to fix it when I'm not using ASP.NET?

Comment: Seems to be an unresolved bug in Boo with .NET 4 ... https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/BOO-1316.  Possible solution posted there to modify the source.

Comment: @Patrick: I saw that, and I rebuilt the assembly with the workaround.  Still getting the same exception.